# Will using .isVisible make a game crash

Tags: android, ios, mobile, lua, coronasdk

I am making an app in Corona Simulator where you have dozens of things going across the screen and when you tap on them then they disappear. I am currently using the `object.isVisable` function and then changing the y coordinate to be off of the screen. The `isVisable` function doesn't get rid of the object it just makes it so that if it gets tapped nothing happens to it. If I do this and a player is catching hundreds of objects, will the game crash because there are too many objects at one time?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just delete the entity?

Comment: You misspelled the property name. It should be [`isVisible`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/isVisible.html). If you don't  need objects why don't you remove them?

Comment: Thanks, I had it isVisable for some of the times and isVisible for the other times. I got that fixed. If i wanted to remove the object could I just use .removeSelf()?